# How to set type for NEXT_HI column in HIBERNATE_UNIQUE_KEY table?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

By default the type of the column is `int(11)`, even if I set up my config like this:

```xml
<id name="id" type="long" column="id">
    <generator class="hilo">
        <param name="max_lo">100</param>
    </generator>
</id>
```

But the column doesn't get `bigint` type as expected. Only `id` columns in entity tables have `bigint`, but not the **hibernate_unique_key** table. It doesn't really make sense.

How do I make this right? How to set up type for `next_hi` column in **hibernate_unique_key**?

Comment: What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: Hibernate version is 3